# trouble setting proper forwarding rules in `iptables` with custom ip address for network sharing

Tags: ssh, networking, forwarding, connection-sharing

I am having issues setting up a bridge for my raspberry pi.

My setup is:
I have a laptop running fedora 27 workstation which is connected to the internet over `wifi`. I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W which is connected to my laptop via `usb` (and only `usb`, no external power, no ethernet, nothing).
I flashed stretch lite image to my pi and then installed `P4wnP1` from here: https://github.com/mame82/P4wnP1
Before i installed `P4wnP1` my pi had a random `169.254.xxx.xxx` address, which is why i changed the ip of my usb ethernet interface to a proper subnet to `ssh` into the pi. After a while i figured out the right setup to get my pi online and download git to clone the repo.

After i ran the `install.sh` and rebooted the pi the pi had a static ip address `172.16.0.1`. And i tried the same thing to get it online, changed the ip of my interface, ssh to the pi, set up the gateway to my fedora machine.
But i cannot get the pi online.

I should probably mention here that i enabled "share connection to other computers" in `network manager` and also tried a lot of things with `iptables`, but i cannot get it to work.

I have spent the past 3 days trying to figure it out, but i had no success.

here is my ifconfig on my fedora:

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s20f0u6i1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.2  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        inet6 fe80::f7f7:80c:8a15:5771  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ee:98:9b:bc:37:ab  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2687  bytes 186674 (182.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1648  bytes 176862 (172.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether c8:5b:76:6b:e4:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xf1200000-f1220000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1982  bytes 177290 (173.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1982  bytes 177290 (173.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:08:e4:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::ebcf:d3b1:5a74:185e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether e4:a7:a0:99:2e:8d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 135496  bytes 72791497 (69.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 51579  bytes 21450089 (20.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

here the `enp0s20f06i3` interface is the one connected to the pi. Before i changed its ip address it had a `10.46.0.1` address, which is also the same address after reboot.

here `route -n` from my pi

```
pi@MAME82-P4WNP1:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.0.2      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 usb0
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

and the ifconfig of my pi

```
pi@MAME82-P4WNP1:~ $ ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 172.16.0.3
        inet6 fe80::cc4b:62ff:fe84:7df0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:4b:62:84:7d:f0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1959  bytes 182340 (178.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3197  bytes 269463 (263.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.24.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.24.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe5e:ceb7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:5e:ce:b7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 14  bytes 1404 (1.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and here `route -n` on my fedora

```
$ route -n                 
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp4s0
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp0s20f0u6i1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp4s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

`resolv.conf` on my pi

```
pi@MAME82-P4WNP1:~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 10.46.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and `/etc/network/interfaces` on my pi

```
pi@MAME82-P4WNP1:~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d


dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

auto usb0

iface usb0 inet manual

auto usb1

iface usb1 inet manual
```

finally my `iptables` on my fedora, where i think the issue is:

```
$ sudo iptables -L                                                          
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:bootps
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
INPUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.42.0.0/24         state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0/24         anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.122.0/24     ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.122.0/24     anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
OUTPUT_direct  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDI_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FWDO_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 
IN_FedoraWorkstation  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
IN_FedoraWorkstation_log  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpts:blackjack:65535 ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:blackjack:65535 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_deny (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain IN_FedoraWorkstation_log (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I think i need to just add the proper entries, but i could not figure it out, i searched a lot of forums.
is there a way to change the `10.46.0.0/24` entries to the `172.16.0.0/24` network?
because my interface had that ip before and if i could just swap the ip in the rules i would be done, right?

I tried `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp4s0 -j MASQUERADE` and also tried to set the rules myself, however i cannot manage to set my `FORWARD` rules accordingly.

Comment: Fedora nic enp0s20f0u6i1 is the nic connected to pi nic usb0?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: Important to note: 172.16.0.0/24 is a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. available addresses 172.16.0.0 - 172.16.0.255. Match the subnet maskes of the 2 nics. [wiki info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork)

Comment: you mean like this `sudo ifconfig enp0s20f0u6 netmask 255.255.255.0`?  i just reconnected the pi, so the interface name changed, it's kinda weird because sometimes it is `enp0s20f0u6` and sometimes `enp0s20f0u6i1` and sometimes `enp0s20f0u6i3`, don't really know why

Comment: As long as the 2 subnet masks match to put both on the same subnet. In your text the usb0 has a mask of 255.255.255.252 and the enp0s20f0u6i3 has a mask of 255.255.0.0 Make both 255.255.255.0 (or what ever). Oh the nic name change thing is called... "[Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)" or something. It can be 'fixed' to always use the same nic [name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/628217/use-of-predictable-network-interface-names-with-alternate-kernels). Or close enough for you to figure out the rest.

Comment: so i put both interfaces on the subnets on `255.255.255.252`, as this is what the pi is using. do i also have to put this mask to my wifi interface?  
i still think it is something to do with my `iptables`
i can ping to my computer `172.16.0.2` from my pi obviously, but nowhere else. sorry if i am kind of dumb here, but i don't have much experience in networking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72061/discussion-between-jc-and-ellusionist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:**

Pi needs Fedora to forward traffic to the internet.

***Pi***

1 network card (that we care about) named:

usb0 -- connected to Fedora.

***Fedora:***

Internet connected.

2 network cards (that we care about) named:

wlp4s0 -- wifi internet

enp0s20f0u6i1 -- connected to the pi.

To make life simpler I recommend stopping the Predictable Network Interface Names thingy. We want to use nic names and do not want them to change on us.

**Step 1:**
Stop systemd's Predictable Network Interface Names thingy by adding "net.ifnames=0" to kernel command line.

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"`

Now update grub:

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

**note:**

I have seen where the value "biosdevname=0" was added to the kernal command line in addition to net.ifnames=0. My setup did not require it.

**Step 2:**

Assign a new name using udev rules by creating a new rule file

`sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/10-myCustom-net.rules`

`SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:f3:79:59", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="test0"`

*MUST* change the `ATTR{address}=="08:00:27:f3:79:59"` line to *your* MAC address.

Change `NAME="test0"` to the name you want to give the nic.

**note:**

Removed `ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0" and ATTR{type}=="1"` from my Ubuntu 14 template.

Some say to remove `KERNEL=="eth*"` or the entire line is ignored. This was not the case in my setup.

If you 'lose' the MAC address like I did because I rebooted before this step, does not show with ifconfig, go find it in `/sys/class/net/assignedName/address`.

BTW: this system renamed it `eth0`, `cat /sys/class/net/eth0/address`

**Step 3:**

Assign the new interface name an address

`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto test0
iface test0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.202 --  use your address
    netmask 255.255.255.0 --  use your address
and what other entries your system requires.
```

**Step 4:**

reboot (its just easier for most of us)

Now that just gives us a static name for our nic.

You will only add iptable rules to Fedora so this is not need on the Pi.

**Assumptions:**

Both Fedora and Pi have default routing tables and no iptable rules.

**note:**

*We want to keep our private ip address private and not public.*

```
RFC1918 name    IP address range    largest CIDR block (subnet mask)
24-bit block    10.0.0.0 – 10.255.255.255   10.0.0.0/8 (255.0.0.0)
20-bit block    172.16.0.0 – 172.31.255.255 172.16.0.0/12 (255.240.0.0)
16-bit block    192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255   192.168.0.0/16 (255.255.0.0)
```

**Pi:**

Assign ip address to *usb0*

`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 172.16.0.1
    netmask 255.240.0.0
add any other values needed.
```

**Fedora:**

Enable ipv4 forwarding

`sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf`

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Assign ip address for test0 (remember we changed the nic name above)

`sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This connects to the Pi
auto test0
iface test0 inet static
    address 172.16.0.2
    netmask 255.240.0.0
add any other values needed.

# This is the internet connection
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.106
    netmask 255.255.255.255
add any other values needed like
    gateway a.b.c.d
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

If wlp4s0 address assigned by DHCP it would look more like this

## This is the internet connection

```
auto wlp4s0
iface wlp4s0 inet dhcp
```

Set the iptable rules to forward the packets from test0 to wlp4s0 AND wrap the packets with a local subnet addressed... wrapper.
Entering rules at the command line.

```
# this rule will forward all traffic from nic test0 to nic wlp4s0
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i test0 -o wlp4s0 -j ACCEPT
# this rule will continue to forward any existing connections from test0 to wlp4so
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i test0 -o wlp4s0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# this rule will wrap the packet with a local address so they do not get lost in transit.
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

**note:**

No firewall rules are enabled. This is a bare minimum to get it working. Add other rules to secure your system.

Make the iptable rules persistent across reboots.

On Ubuntu16 the package name is `iptables-persistent`. Fedora may be different.

`sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent`

Save the current iptable rules

`iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

**Reboot fedora.**

**Verify:**

ip addresses.

iptable rules

Comment: Please note I changed the subnet mask to 255.240.0.0 on the 172 network to keep it a private address.